# request to IIS gets aborted

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Facing a strange problem.

Two of my applications are running in the same server except their port numbers differ.

Both are developed using VS 2010 and deployed to IIS on a test server running windows 2003.

I'm accessing both the application using IE 9 and IE 10, GC and FF.  Application A is accessible through all of the browsers, whereas Application B is inconsistent and gets aborted most of the times when using IE series.

My question is why the first thing the request gets aborted ?[image: issueimage]

Dont' know how to proceed, the network team also has no idea on this issue.  Advise and pointers on will of help.

Thanks

Comment: from your client machine, can you telnet over the server using its port number - 9091?

Comment: You need to check if 9091 is open or not